# glibc detected *** free(): invalid pointer: Python c++ and Swig

Tags: c++, python, swig

I have to run some unit tests which are written in Python. We have the code to test in c++, so I compiled it into a shared object and using swig providing an interface for the python scripts to call into the necessary api's to test.

Now when i run one of the python scripts (it is obviously accessing the c++ codebase which i intend to test), i am getting a "glibc detected free(): invalid pointer". Now I do understand that there is some memory issue, either a double free or I am freeing an inaccessible memory. Now what i am requesting from you experts:

1] I am not getting any backtrace(no line number even), is there anyway to know where the issue is happening? I am not getting any info other than the script stopping abruptly at some point and printing something like this
*** glibc detected *** free(): invalid pointer: 0x099e9b28 ***
Can i get a backtrace somehow? By setting some flag may be?

2] I ran valgrind:
"valgrind --leak-check=yes ./myscript.py"
 I did not get something much, some lines from it:
 glibc detected  free(): invalid pointer: 0x099e9b28
==25728==
==25728== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==25728==    at 0x625AEA: PyObject_Free (in /usr/lib/libpython2.3.so.1.0)
==25728==    by 0x614C7F: (within /usr/lib/libpython2.3.so.1.0)
==25728==    by 0x61EA53: (within /usr/lib/libpython2.3.so.1.0)

I am not getting anything related to my code basically. So is there something else i should do with valgrind.

3] I tried printfs, its taking me to nothing actually.
4] I tried gdb:
prompt>gdb python
gdb> set args myscript.py
gdb> run

This runs the script, I could not set any breakpoints, it runs and prints the error. No absolute help. Is there something else i should do with GDB? Any way to set breakpoints?

Thanks a lot for any kind of pointer you guys can give me.

Comment: I don't know how to use GDB, but I have debugged such problems using Visual Studio. What I do is add an `input` statement at the beginning of the script to pause it. When it's paused there, with the DLL (or .so) project loaded in VS I attach it to python.exe. Now you can set breakpoints in your C++ code, and the debugger may even break automatically when that error is thrown.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I tried it I am using command line gdb, when i add input, its expecting that input, how shall i set breakpoints? I mean whatever i type when it is expecting input, gets interpreted as input. Hence i cannot set breakpoints then. Is there something else i should do?

Comment: Hmm, the VS workflow is significantly different. While the python script is paused (expecting user input) you can interact with the VS IDE and set breakpoints (after attaching to the running python process). Then you hit enter to resume script execution. I have no idea how this translates to using GDB.

Answer (score 1):

I finally figured out! I executed the command
ulimit -c unlimited

After this i see a core dump, now i can analyse it via
gdb /usr/bin/python2.3 core.31685

Answer (score 0):

I have successfully debugged this type of problem using Google's [heap checker](http://google-perftools.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/doc/heap_checker.html). It will give you the stack traces both of the point of allocation and deallocation.